# How to configure SSRS without using my Windows login and password?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The way SSRS in my project works, it requires my Windows User Login and password in the web.config file of the ASP.NET application which calls the reports. This is a problem since i have to change the password every 90 days as a security measure. Is it possible to configure SSRS without any employees Login and password ?

This is the part that worries me

```
<add key="ReportServerUsername" value="me" />
<add key="ReportServerPassword" value="my password" />
<add key="ReportServerDomainname" value="my domain />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set it up to use impersonated/delegated credentials.

You will have to configure the web application to use integrated authentication, then set the correct attribute in the config file.

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

If done this way, each user will be accessing the database using their own username and password, so  you will want to set up security appropriately. This means creating

- NT Group - Add users to this group
- Server Login - Create a DB login for the group
- DB user - create a db user for the login
- db role - create a db role, and assign it to the login
- Permissions - give the role the needed permissions on database objects

Comment: Okay but you are referring to application authentication. What do i now set in those SSRS items i added in question above ?

Comment: @Moko58, you don't need those values at all. Use integrated authentication instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx